# How to pass prop in styledcomponent to stylerule?

Tags: reactjs, css, styled-components

I am using styledcomponents in my reactjs app. In one of the components I have a mediarule:

```
@media (max-width: 1450px)
{
  padding-right: ${props => (props.meta.count > 0 ? '6px' : '0')};
}
```

This meta.count prop does exist but when I run the app I get:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'count' of undefined
```

The render starts like this:

```
const { lastUpdated, meta } = this.props;
```

The meta prop gets loaded through a redux selector:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  meta: getAlertsMeta(state),
});
```

How can I avoid this / fix this?

Comment: could you console.log and check what is `props.meta` and `props`.it looks like you are using a functional component..am i right?

Comment: Can you also show the code where define the styled component, and the render() method in which you use it?

Comment: @MatteoGesmundo I updated the question.